# Postgres 8.4 server not starting on Redhat after crash

Tags: redhat, postgresql

I am not a Database Admin but have to take care of this request.
The PostgreSQL Server crashed during an update. Now I am unable to start it again.

The process id dead. When I am trying to stop the server. I get this message

```
m: cannot remove `/var/run/postmaster.8053.pid': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove `/var/lock/subsys/postgresql': Read-only file system
```

When I try to start the server, the following message is coming

```
Starting postgresql service: /etc/init.d/postgresql: line 183: /var/lib/pgsql/pgstartup.log: Read-only file system
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you starting the database as superuser? What are the permissions on the log file?

Comment: Yes, I am starting as Superuser and the logfile has rw permission for root

Comment: What's the output of 'mount'?

Comment: It is possible that your `/var` partition is mounted as read-only.

Comment: There was some problem with the file system.A hard reboot solved the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the crash is related to a storage failure, even momentarily, the kernel sometimes chooses to remount the file system read-only to prevent further damage.  You can undo that using

```
mount -o remount,rw /whatever
```

Also check the `errors` option on the `mount` man page about this behavior.

A reboot is of course also an option to clean this up.